# Ordereddict has no attribute caled "..."

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload an object in json format using api_view(), in django-rest-framework.

serializers :

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'unit_price', 'price_with_tax', 'slug', 'inventory',        'collection']
   
    price_with_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='calculate_tax')
    
    def calculate_tax(self, product: Product) :
        return product.unit_price * Decimal(1.1)
```

views:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])  
def product_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Product.objects.select_related('collection').all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request':request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) 
        serializer.validated_data 
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Collection and Products models:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+', blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    inventory = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion, blank=True)
```

this is the object I'm trying to upload and create:

```
{
    "title": "a",
    "slug": "a",
    "unit_price": 1,
    "collection": 1,
    "inventory": 1,
}
```

I tried to get rid of the calculate_tax part, because the error raised in that part but nothing really crossed my mind besides that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serializers.SerializerMethodField are read-only.
This function is not being called during the validation process. It is being read when you want to serialize an instance. methods prefixed with validate_(yourmodel_fieldname) would perform validation, in case you needed it. But that's not the case.

In your post handle section in view.py you don't create instances because you only validate the data, but never actually create it. I assume you want to create a Product. So you likely are looking for is something like the following:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    product = Product.objects.create(**serializer.validated_data)
    return Response(ProductSerializer(product, many=False).data, status=201)
```

1. You check if serializer is valid. If it is, you go ahead and create a Product instance that takes the valid fields as input.
2. This new product instance that you created you have it as a variable called product.
3. It is now passed down to your ProductSerializer that will calculate taxes as well for you when invoking ProductSerializer(product...

Note that it's usual to have custom methods such as price with taxes directly in the model, specially if the tax is fixed like  1.1

Notice that it would be a method. Not a field in the database. Having it in the model is more flexible than under serializer so that you can access it for other functionalities that you may add. Let's say you have a view that filter prices with taxes. Having access to product.price_with_tax can be handy later on.

Comment: thank you for all the advises and the answer as well <3